# Creating a table with indicator functions for combinations

Tags: r

I have 50 combinations and I would like to make a table that have 0 or 1, for its value. For example,

```
x1= c(01, 34, 67, 09)        
x2= c(01, 22, 09, 78)      
x3= c(09, 83, 45, 82)        
x4= c(23, 89, 04, 44)             
x5= c(04, 44, 97, 56)        
.
.
.
x50=c(78, 90, 88, 00)
```

wanted:

```
01  02  03  04 ... 09 ... 34 ... 67 ... 99
 1   0   0   0      1      1      1      0      # for the first row
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good chance for matrix indexing, using a row/col combination to assign all the 1s in a single operation:

```
xl <- mget(paste0("x", 1:5))
mat <- matrix(0, nrow=length(xl), ncol=99)
mat[cbind(rep(seq_along(xl), lengths(xl)), unlist(xl))] <- 1

mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] ...
#[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
#[2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
#[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
#[4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
#[5,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0 ...
```

Comment: hi,what if I have a data frame?(i.e., data frame "x" that includes all the combinations as rows)

Comment: @Mathygroupy - no big drama, you could make the indexes like `mat[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), unlist(df))] <- 1` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `tidyverse`. I only used the first five combinations as an example. `dat` is the final output.

```
x1 <- c(01, 34, 67, 09)        
x2 <- c(01, 22, 09, 78)      
x3 <- c(09, 83, 45, 82)        
x4 <- c(23, 89, 04, 44)             
x5 <- c(04, 44, 97, 56) 

library(tidyverse)

# Get the five combinations as a list 
dat_list <- mget(x = paste0("x", 1:5))

dat <- dat_list %>%
  # Convert to a tibble
  as_tibble() %>%
  # Convert to long format
  gather(x, value) %>%
  # Create an indicator with presence = 1L
  mutate(indicator = 1L) %>%
  # Complete the combination between x and value, fill the NA with 0
  complete(x, value = 1:99, fill = list(indicator = 0L)) %>%
  # Convert to wide format
  spread(value, indicator) %>%
  # Remove x
  select(-x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `table`

```
lst <- mget(ls(pattern = "^x\\d+$"))

mat <- t(sapply(lst, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = 1:max(sapply(lst, max))))))
#   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
#x1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#x2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
#x3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#x4 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
#x5 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#   29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53
#x1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#x2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#x3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#x4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#x5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#   54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78
#x1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#x2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
#x3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#x4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#x5  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#   79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97
#x1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#x2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#x3  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#x4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#x5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

---

### Sample data

```
x1= c(01, 34, 67, 09)
x2= c(01, 22, 09, 78)
x3= c(09, 83, 45, 82)
x4= c(23, 89, 04, 44)
x5= c(04, 44, 97, 56)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using `sapply` assuming you know the maximum value these vector can take (considered 99 here)

```
t(sapply(mget(paste0("x", 1:5)), function(x) +(1:99 %in% x)))

#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] ......
#x1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1 ......  
#x2    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1 ......    
#x3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1 ......    
#x4    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0 ......    
#x5    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0 ......
```

**data**

```
x1 <- c(01, 34, 67, 09)
x2 <- c(01, 22, 09, 78)
x3 <- c(09, 83, 45, 82)
x4 <- c(23, 89, 04, 44)
x5 <- c(04, 44, 97, 56)
```